# how to change paddings in dialog window in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, dialog, android-alertdialog, android-jetpack-compose

I need to write a composable function that, like a dialog window, will be displayed over the rest of the screen elements. I wrap the contents of my composable function in Dialog(). But there are paddings on all sides of the screen. How can they be removed?

[screenshot of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtjnO.jpg), red lines are paddings that need to be removed

I use dialog in my function something like this:

```
@Composable
fun MyFunction(){
  Dialog(onDismissRequest = { }) {
    //content
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
        @Composable
        fun MyFunction(){
        Dialog(onDismissRequest = { },
        properties = DialogProperties(usePlatformDefaultWidth = false)) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        //content
      }
    }
  }
```